# Ruby Gem adaptor MySQL error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.8.7

I am getting the below error while using the MySQL gem; Tried mysql2 and it also gives the same error.

```
-bash-4.1$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

mysql (2.9.1)

-bash-4.1$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]


-bash-4.1$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'mysql'
NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql
    from ./mysql.rb:10
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
irb(main):002:0>
```

Please let me know if there is a solution for this; thanks!

Comment: I know this is kinda obvious but i'm just putting it out there, did you run `gem install mysql`? or `bundle install`?

Comment: @Thermatix Yes I did gem install mysql for installing mysql gem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bundler/rvm? If so, start irb with:

```
bundle exec irb
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the right `gemset` and `ruby version` from where you are accessing the gem.
Before typing in the `irb`, check what gemset you are in:

```
rvm gemset list
```

then check the gems installed in that particular gemset

```
rvm <my-gemset-name> do gem list
```

If they do not match, that is your problem and you can fix it by changing to the right gemset:

```
 rvm use <my-gemset>
```

Similarly, check for ruby version, i.e if the ruby version for your installed gem and from where you are running your irb match